# All users in a room join another room

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I would like that all users in a room (`roomOne`) join another room (`roomTwo`). I tried that code :

```
io.to('roomOne').join('roomTwo');
```

But it doesn't work. I got that error :

```
TypeError: io.to(...).join is not a function
```

How could I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop through the sockets connected to the room and ,one by one, join the new room

```
var clients = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[oldroom].sockets;  

for (var clientId in clients ) {
  io.sockets.connected[clientId].join(newroom);
}
```

(socket.io version: 1.4.5)